# Meaning of "far and few between" in this context

Tags: idioms

I came across the following sentence in "[The Carpetbagger Report](http://www.thecarpetbaggerreport.com/archives/11490.html)":

> The administration published this afternoon a newly released, and
>   surprisingly short, declassified summary of the key judgments of the
>   National Intelligence Estimate on al Qaeda. The document is online for
>   all to see.
>
> The startling new revelations are ... far and few between. The terrorist
>   network is rebuilding, its leadership is located largely in tribal
>   areas of Pakistan, and it’s still focused on committing acts of terror
>   ‘without requiring a centralized terrorist organization, training camp
>   or leader.”

Can someone explain the meaning of the phrase "... **far and few between**" in that context?

Presumably it is an idiom, but I have not been able to find its meaning on the internet.

Comment: I don't know what you're searching, but it's the first hit on Google

Comment: @simchona: I'm searching for the meaning of "far and few between" in that context. If you take a look in its ngram, you will see that it is a rare idiom.

Comment: Carlo_R, there is an idiom ["few and far between"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/few+and+far+between) that means not many and widely scattered. I think this is just a play on that, especially with the ... before it. I'm not 100% sure of the writer's intended meaning.

Comment: @simchona: Please, see this nGram http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=far+and+few+between%2C+few+and+far+between&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: @simchona: Presumably JLG is right when he say that the journalist uses "..." before the inverted-idiom to create a play.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Please stop addressing comments to me. I can read his answer for myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Far and few between" is a sorry mangling of idiomatic *[few and far  between](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/few+and+far+between)*, which as noted in link means "very few; few and widely scattered".  The phrase as used in "[The Carpetbagger Report](http://www.thecarpetbaggerreport.com/archives/11490.html)" breaks down into the phrases "revelations are few between" and either "revelations are far" or "revelations are far between", of which only the last makes sense.

Comment: +1 A sorry mangling indeed. Maybe the Carpetbagger was trying to be clever.

Answer (score 1):

I think the phrase:

> The startling new revelations are ... far and few between.

Can be read as

> There are very few startling new revelations.

Or more clearly:

> Of all the revelations, very few are new and startling.

Answer (score -1):

*Few and far* is an idiomatic phrase, meaning not many but maybe two or three. As in the sentence: "piano techniques are few and far".